# How to use a List<Tuple<>> as an action method parameter?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to send a `List<Tupple<>>` to a controller but I'm not doing it well because I always get the message `No parameterless constructor defined for this object` and the method's code doesn't get executed.

I'm using a class as a view-model for the controller arguments:

```cs
public class InsurancesHospitals
{
    public int hospital { get; set; }
    public List<Tuple<int, string, bool>> insurances { get; set; }
}
```

This is the controller:

```cs
[Authorize]
public ActionResult AssociateInsurances(InsurancesHospitals viewModel)
{
    foreach (var insurance in viewModel.insurances)
    {
        /*
            Here I do some things...
        */
    }

    return Redirect("/Hospitals/Index");
}
```

And this is the view from where I call the controller:

```html
<form id="formulario" role="form" method="post" action="~/Hospitals/AssociateInsurances">

    <label class="control-label" for="hospital">Hospital</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="hospital" name="hospital">
        @foreach (var hospital in (IQueryable<HOSPITALS>)ViewData["hospitals"])
        {
            <option value="@hospital.ID" >@hospital.NAME</option>
        }
    </select>

    <div class="col-xs-12">
        <div class="row">
            @{
                var insurances = ((IQueryable<INSURANCES>)ViewData["insurances"]).ToList();

                for (var index=0; index < insurances.Count(); index++) 
                {
                    <input type="hidden" value="@insurances[index].ID" class="insurances" name="insurances[@index].Item1" />

                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-id="@insurances[index].ID" class="association" name="insurances[@index].Item3" />
                        @insurances[index].NAME
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-xs-3">
                        <input type="text"  data-id="@insurances[index].ID" class="form-control codes" name="insurances[@index].Item2" />
                    </div>
                }
            }
        </div>
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit">
        <span>Associate</span>
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: Any reason you *need* to use `Tuple<int,string,bool>` rather than just define a class with 3 properties? I always find using a `Tuple<>` complicates the code, and makes it less readable than a simple object with named properties.

Comment: Not really but I didn't want to create a class for that to be honest.

Comment: Why not? It'll take <1 minute!

Comment: Ok, I try it with a class then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like the error says: a tuple [has no parameterless constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd387150(v=vs.110).aspx), so the model binder can't instantiate it.

You can go the hard way: create your own model binder, or the easy way: simply introduce a new class that holds the appropriate properties. This has an added bonus: actually useful property names as opposed to `ItemN`.

Comment: Well, that was the problem. I won't use Tuple again as an action method parameter. Using a class was the solution. Thanks to you and  Jamiec ;)